# Accessing pixels inside the egde boundry of an image in c#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am doing some image processing parts for hand detection, and i have done some of the essential parts such as hand color detection. And then edge detection. My problem is that i want to access the pixels inside the edge boundary,so that i can label the entire hand gesture part.

> I want to mark the region inside the edge as either `completely black
>   or completely white`.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: How is an *edge* defined as a data structure?

Comment: Does your edge detection algorithm cause a perfect contour to be made around the target? If so, just use flood-fill.

Comment: Hello Mr. David ,I have tried flood fill after edge detection on human skin detected output image, but it doesn't yield better output. I want to make hand gestures recognizable in future, any ideas?

Comment: So you need an algorithm to fill the inside of the edges. But what is the input to that algorithm? What is an *edge*?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr)
I want to recognize hand gestures. Firstly i have segmented hand postures, then accordingly as hue value of human hand, i detected hand pixels, now i have an edge denoting hand, but the pixels inside the hand edge are unnecessary, so i want to completely remove them.